# Unhex mixed content in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-requests

I have the following code which requests data via post:

```
response_data = requests.post('http://example.com/ajax', data={'foo':'bar'}).text
print response_data  # "\u003Cdiv class=\u0022red\u0022\u003E..."
print type(response_data)  # <type 'unicode'>
```

I'd like to get the following: `<div class="red">`

As I see it I should pass some param to `requests` to tell that response should be deserialized.

`response_data.decode('string_escape')` and `response_data.encode('utf-8')` does not help.

Comment: Does `response_data = response_data.decode('string_escape')` helps?

Comment: What is the service you're posting to, and why is it encoding that response data?

Comment: Did you mean `requests.post('http://example.com/ajax', data={'foo':'bar'}).text`?

Comment: `response_data.encode("utf8")`?

Comment: forgot `.text` method

Comment: nothing from above comments helps. As I think requests improperly encodes response source code into unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appeared `json.loads(response_data)` solves the problem (though content not packed in json object, rather just json string). All because of my inattention.

Comment: A json string *is* a json object.  You can use `respond_data.json()`.  The `requests` module supports JSON directly.